# Set content type without charset

Tags: php, apache, character-encoding, http-headers, content-type

I'm trying to set the header `Content-Type` to `text/html`, but without specifying the charset. If I run the following code:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html');
var_dump(headers_list());
```

I get the following output:

```
['Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8']
```

The `charset` parameter is added automatically! And `Content-Type` is changed to `Content-type`. The same happens with any content type with the type `text`. For example `Content-Type: text/foobar` becomes `Content-type: text/foobar;charset=UTF-8`.

If I specify any additional parameters, they are kept. For example `Content-Type: text/foobar; param=value` becomes `Content-type: text/foobar; param=value;charset=UTF-8`.

If I specify the `charset` parameter, the header is not changed. For example `Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1` stays `Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1`. In this case, the header field name is not changed from `Content-Type` to `Content-type` either.

If I specify a content type that has a type other than `text`, the header is not changed. For example `Content-Type: foo/bar` stays the same.

Is it not possible to specify a text-based content type without the `charset` parameter? I'm using PHP 7.1.1 and Apache 2.4.26.

Comment: In your `php.ini` find `default_charset="UTF-8"` and replace it with an empty string. It might break stuff tho, see http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset

Comment: @rndus2r A global setting change is entirely unsuitable.  We need a way to prevent PHP adding the charset as and when required, particularly when serving content that may, on an ad-hoc basis, have a different charset, or declare its own (in the case of HTML).

Comment: It doesn't matter that `Content-Type` is changed to `Content-type`: it's case insensitive.  However, your salient point appears to be a bug in PHP - see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have encountered what I believe to be a bug in PHP:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75922

I have confirmed that the following can be used as a workaround:

```php
$defaultCharset = \ini_get('default_charset');
\ini_set('default_charset', '');
\header('Content-Type: text/html');
\ini_set('default_charset', $defaultCharset);
```

Setting the `default_charset` to an empty string before calling `header()` prevents PHP appending the `charset` parameter (tested with PHP 7.3).  However, as ["Setting `default_charset` to an empty value is not recommended"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset), the code above immediately restores the previous value (it does not appear to matter that the headers are not actually sent until the first part of the content is).

In my case, there are some hardcoded HTML files to serve with a different charset to the default, declared in a `<meta>` element.

(I also found that `\header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=')` seems to work in Firefox and Chrome, but does result in an empty `charset` parameter in the HTTP header, which may cause issues with some browser versions.)

Comment: Thanks for using built-in functions with default name space qualifier.